# jqgrid. Hide subgrid on collapse?

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net, subgrid

I have a page with a grid allowing subgrids. I would like the user to be able to enter data in one subgrid, collapse it, and enter data in another subgrid, and so on... The data entered should be saved to the server with one call (or discarded).
It seems however that when collapsing a subgrid it dissapears from the DOM.
Is there an easy way to hide it instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exact solution of your problem could depend on details of your current implementation. Whyt you can to do for example is to use [subGridRowColapsed](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3asubgrid#events) callback or `jqGridSubGridRowColapsed` event to save editing row/cell *before* the grid will be collapsed. Another option `reloadOnExpand: false` of [subGridOptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3asubgrid#properties) could be helpful too. It inform jqGrid that you prefer to hide collapsed subgrid instead of deleting it.

Comment: Thank you! `reloadOnExpand: false` is the way to go in my case.